# Dropdown List is Refusing to Bind Records Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to populate my dropdownlist but I am getting the following error

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')

In my `View Controller` I am using the following:

```
return View(await _context.MISobject.Include(C => C.StafMemeberdsOCM1).Include(C => C.StafMemeberdsOCM2).Include(c => c.MISPrioritys).ToListAsync());
```

And in my Class I have the following properties:

```
public int? Priority { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Priority")]
public virtual MISPriority MISPrioritys { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<MISPriority> MISPriorityList { get; set; }
```

Obviously the reason the error is because `MISPriorityList`  is empty it does not know about the data so how do I fetch the records correctly to ensure the items appear in the drop down list. 
As you can see from screen shot below there is data in the `MISPrioritys` table.

[image: Data in the prioritys table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `MISPriority`  to `MISobject`.

```
var mISobject = await _context.MISobject.Include(C => C.StafMemeberdsOCM1).Include(C => C.StafMemeberdsOCM2).Include(c => c.MISPrioritys).ToListAsync();

var mISPriorityList = _context.MISPriority.ToList();

mISobject.MISPriorityList = mISPriorityList;

return View(mISobject);
```